# Accessing static variable in same class getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'demo1')

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two static objects inside a DemoService as follows

```
export class DemoService {

  public static demo1 = {
    ACTIVITY: 'ACTIVITY'
  };

  public static anotherVariable: Array<Model> = [{
      title: DemoService.demo1.ACTIVITY // THIS IS THE ERROR LINE
  }]

}
```

I am getting an error that says DemoService is undefined. I've used this type of structure until now, but since I have upgraded to Angular 15 it throws this at run time. Any solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try with `this.demo1.ACTIVITY`?

Comment: @MishaMashina, We cannot access static variables or methods using "this"

Comment: @shrey shah , that’s not true. It depends on context.

Comment: @EvgenyGurevich Yes you are correct we can use this for static variables but only inside static methods. On non-static methods or other static objects, we need to access them with their Class name

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution,
It is because of the target to **ES2022** in **tsconfig.json**, by changing it to **ES2021** it started working.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "ES2021"
  }
}
```

For more info, you can check
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52004

Answer (score 0):

Direct fix for this problem:

```
export class DemoService {

  public static demo1: any = {
    ACTIVITY: 'ACTIVITY'
  };

  public static anotherVariable: Array<Model> = [{
      title: DemoService.demo1.ACTIVITY
}]

}
```

Comment: How this is a fix? Adding "any" won't make any difference.